# Regexreplace - How to remove newlines located between parentheses?

Tags: regexp-replace

I have a string of code that looks like

```
int main() {
double first, second, temp;
printf("Enter first number: ");
scanf("%lf", &first);
printf("Enter second number: ");
scanf("%lf", &second);
}
```

I want to run a *Perl-compatible regex-replace* to transform this code into

```
int main() {double first, second, temp;printf("Enter first number: ");scanf("%lf", &first);printf("Enter second number: ");scanf("%lf", &second);}
```

I've tried \n(?=[^{}]*}) but it only removes the new line preceding the {. Note that I do not want to remove any spaces or anything else. I only want to remove the new lines that are between the curly brackets.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand, but from your output all that you seem to want to do is remove all newlines? For which you would not even have to use regex.

Comment: I want to remove newlines, but there is other text in the larger file like comments that I don't want to touch.

Comment: So your actual question is 'how do I remove \n from those portions in my text that start with { and end with }? Or are there more {} blocks?

Comment: This can be very brittle, but you might try `(?:^[^\r\n{}]+{(?=[^{}]*})|\G(?!^))[^\r\n]*\K\r?\n` https://regex101.com/r/ub4S8k/1